# About stationary equation of conservation law.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R^N})$, $a\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^N,\mathbb{R}^N)$, $\lambda>0$. With $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$, we consider that $Y(s;x)$ is the solution of $$Y_s(s;x)=a(Y(s;x)),\text{ }s>0,\textbf{ }Y(0,x)=x.$$

The Cauchy-Lipchitz theorem tells us that the problem above has unique solution.

Put: $$u(x)=\int_0^{\infty}f(Y(s;x))e^{-\lambda s}ds.$$ Assume $u$ is $C^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

---

Prove that:
$$a\cdot \nabla u+\lambda u=f$$

Comment: $a$ is a function of type $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited the problem!